# cannot set currentTime of dynamically added video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I added a video element dynamically using javascript. I then try to set the currentTime property, but it does not change. Im using python-django. Any ideas?

example:

var video = document.createElement(‘video’);

var source = document.createElement(‘source’);

source.src = ‘video.webm’;

video.appendChild(source);

document.body.appendChild(video);

video.addEventListener(‘load’, function(){ video.currentTime = 60 })

video.load();

Comment: If you post an example that reproduces the problem, your problem will be easier to solve. Just a guess: perhaps the video hasn't loaded yet, and you should set the time inside a `load` event listener on the video (e.g. `video.addEventListener("load", function(){ video.currentTime = 50 })`)

Comment: I added an example, I tried the listener but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Here it's working as expected.The only thing I noticed is that you were using a strange single quote, that generated a error on my console: "SyntaxError: illegal character". I used then double quotes in everything.

```
var video = document.createElement("video");    
var source = document.createElement("source");    
source.src = "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4";    
video.appendChild(source);    
document.body.appendChild(video);
video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(){
    video.currentTime = 10;
    video.play();
});
```